# Google Sheets Filter function returns: #ERROR - 'formula parse error'

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I am using the filter function in a master sheet to grab data from 2 other sheets in google sheets. Both of these sheets go through row M.

When I run the filter functions individually, they both run.

```
=FILTER('Query Manual'!A2:M,'Query Manual'!A2:A<>"")
=FILTER('Query CSI'!A2:M,'Query CSI'!A2:A<>"")
```

But when I combine them I get a formula parse error with the #ERROR response.

```
 =(FILTER('Query Manual'!A2:M,'Query Manual'!A2:A<>""), FILTER('Query CSI'!A2:M,'Query CSI'!A2:A<>""))
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error when I put the two together, but individually they each work fine?

Comment: I substituted ; for , but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
={FILTER('Query Manual'!A2:M,'Query Manual'!A2:A<>""); FILTER('Query CSI'!A2:M,'Query CSI'!A2:A<>"")}
```

Curly Brackets instead of commas. I put on my reading glasses and realized this lol.

Comment: Parenthesis not commas. I need to sleep

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to fix any typos.